# Can I have Radeon 6950 + RX 580 installed together on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, gpu, amd-radeon, dual-gpu

I'm a game dev and I use RX 580 as my main GPU. I'd like to install older Radeon 6950 and optimize the game for it. I plan to use two displays.

I tried doing this on Windows 7, but it's impossible for me to install two different versions of driver (there's no driver which supports both GPUs).

I installed display drivers through Device Manager to prevent possible issues with Radeon control center. When I installed second driver, the first device shown yellow warning icon and stopped working (no matter which was first).

I've read Windows 10 has better support for multiple GPUs. Would this work on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

A computer can install several graphics cards, not depending on what version of the operating system, but rather depends on the slot on the motherboard with several discrete graphics cards.
If it is a low-end motherboard, there is usually only one PCI-E slot for a discrete graphics card. Then you can only install a separate graphics card.
If it is a mid-range or medium-to-high-end motherboard, then at least two discrete graphics card PCI-E slots can form a dual-channel graphics card, and the performance is greatly improved.

1. Specifically, it depends on whether there is a graphics card slot on the motherboard to support the installation of 2 graphics cards;
2. Install dual graphics card can be set to graphics card crossfire or SLI, which can enhance the performance output of the graphics card;
3. Crossfire only makes high-end graphics cards meaningful. The low-end midrange does not have any meaning at all. The graphics card must be supported by the same brand and the same chip.

According to your description, the RX 580 and Radeon 6950 are different models, so even if our computer's motherboard supports the use of two graphics cards at the same time, because the two graphics cards are not the same model, they cannot be used at the same time.